# How to "repaint" a JLayeredPane by index

Tags: java, jlayeredpane

I'm trying to make a game of snakes and ladders and because my snakes and ladders are randomly generated, i'm adding my board at a JLayeredPane with index(1) and the snakes and ladders with index(2). So my question is. Can i clear just the content of index(2) so i can draw new snakes and ladders? Because there is suppose to be a spacial block that makes the ladders-snakes and the snakes-ladders.

Comment: There is a `getComponentsInLayer(int layer)` method, you may use this and "clear" the components from this layer .

Comment: That helped! thank you!